# TypeError when instantiating a deque and then popping

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to understand why I am getting this `TypeError` when instantiating my `deque`. I am solving the "Number of Islands" problem

```
def bfs(r,c):
    q = collections.deque((r,c))
    while q:
        r_curr, c_curr = q.popleft()
        for dr, dc in dirs:
            r_next, c_next = r_curr + dr, c_curr + dc
            if is_valid(r_next, c_next):
                visited.add((r_next, c_next))
                q.append((r_next, c_next))
```

Gives me the below error:

```
TypeError: cannot unpack non-iterable int object
    r_curr, c_curr = q.popleft()
```

But the below works without error.

```
def bfs(r,c):
    q = collections.deque()
    q.append((r,c))
    while q:
        r_curr, c_curr = q.popleft()
        for dr, dc in dirs:
            r_next, c_next = r_curr + dr, c_curr + dc
            if is_valid(r_next, c_next):
                visited.add((r_next, c_next))
                q.append((r_next, c_next))
```

Why does the first method fail but the second method works?

Comment: because `q = collections.deque((r,c))` creates a deque with two elements in it (each an int) and `q = collections.deque(); q.append((r,c))` creates a deque with *one* element in it, a tuple of ints.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting the error when `popleft`ing from `deque` not when instantiating it. Because your deque has two elements at the start (`r` and `c`) not one tuple `(r, c)`. To have a tuple in deque initialize it like so:

```
q = collections.deque([(r,c)])
```

Answer (score 1):

`deque` takes an iterable, using the elements to form itself. So `deque((r, c))` gives you the deque equivalent of `(r, c)`. You want this to be a deque with one item: `(r, c)`, not two items: `r` and `c`, so you must use `deque(((r, c),))`.